# why is my CountRecur method not working, ive tried to comb through it but no dice

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, count, recurrence

Why is my CountRecur method not working? I've tried to comb through it but no dice. I know it's not all that well optimized, but I've tried everything and I thought I might give this a shot.

Assume that StrArr1 is already in alphabetical order, and that all the strings in it are words that may occur more than once, they're also all in low caps. The remove recur works fine, I tested it.

```
public void CountRecur() {
    ArrayList <String> StrArr2 = new ArrayList <String> ();
    StrArr2 = StrArr1;
    this.RemoveRecur(StrArr2);
    int count = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= StrArr2.size(); i++) {
        if (count != 0) {
            IntArr.add(count);
        }
        count = 0;
        if (i < StrArr2.size()) {
        while (j < StrArr1.size() && StrArr2.get(i).equals(StrArr1.get(j))) {
            count++;
            j++;
            }
        }
    }
}   

public void RemoveRecur(ArrayList <String> StrArr3) {
    int i = 1;
    while (i < StrArr3.size()) {
        if (StrArr3.get(i).equals(StrArr3.get(i - 1))) {
            StrArr3.remove(i - 1);
            i = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Assigning StrArr2 = new ArrayLIst is wasteful and pointless since on the next line you assign it to StrArr1. Just declare it that way: ArrayList<String> StrArr2 = StrArr1; and skip the new ArrayList part. 2) It's hard to follow your CountRecur method, the code is pretty badly written and not easy to follow. What exactly is the intent of the method and what is your exact question including what results you are getting and expect to get?

Comment: From what I can see of your code, you are trying to eliminate duplicate Strings from a List of String and then capture the count of how many duplicates were found and removed, is that correct? And where is the 'Recurrence part of your code`?

Comment: To count the amount of times a string repeats in StrArr1. i know i dont even need strarr2 in theory, but i tried everything and this got me a little closer to a solution

Comment: Strarr1 is an instance variable in the class for these methods

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to count the number of occurances of a String in a List of Strings, this can be done much easier using a Map to store the string as a Key and keep a count as the value in the map. Here is a much simpler method that achieves what you want using the Map concept:

```
public  Map<String, Integer> CountStrings(List<String> strings) {
    Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();

    for(String aString: strings){
        Integer count = counts.get(aString);
        count = (count == null) ? 1 : ++count;
        counts.put(aString, count);
    }

    return counts;
}
```

You should really follow commonly used standards in Java and use camel-case for both method and variables names. The `CountStrings` method should be: `countStrings`, `StrArr1` should be `strArr1`, etc.

Comment: lol i just checked in after solving it. i tried my original idea and found the silly mistake i was making. it was actually pretty easy.

Comment: public void CountRecur() {
  int j = 0;
  int count = 0;
  int i = 0;
  while (i < StrArr1.size()) {
   count = 0;
    while (j < StrArr1.size()
      && StrArr1.get(i).equals(StrArr1.get(j))) {
     count++;
     j++;
    }
     i = j;
     IntArr.add(count);
  }
 }